# Unable to use ToIntFunction<T> instead of Function<T, Integer> in Collectors.toMap - Based on SonarQube reported codesmell

Tags: java, java-8, sonarqube, java-stream, collectors

I'm trying various options in Java 8 streams. Now converting a list into a map. Please see below code sample.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.ToIntFunction;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

public class MainTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    MainTest obj = new MainTest();
    obj.testFunc();
  }

  private void testFunc() {

    List<Hosting> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Hosting(1, "liquidweb.com", 80000));
    list.add(new Hosting(2, "linode.com", 90000));
    list.add(new Hosting(3, "digitalocean.com", 120000));
    list.add(new Hosting(4, "aws.amazon.com", 200000));
    list.add(new Hosting(5, "mkyong.com", 1));

    // No issues With lambda expression
    Map<Integer, String> resultWithLambda =
        list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getId(), x -> x.getName()));

    // No issues With method reference
    Map<Integer, String> resultWithMethodRef =
        list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Hosting::getId, Hosting::getName));

    // No Issues With java.util.function.Function
    Map<Integer, String> resultWithFuncMapper =
        list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(sampleMapper, Hosting::getName));

    // Compile time error with java.util.function.ToIntFunction

    // The method toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K>, Function<? super T,? extends U>) in the
    // type Collectors is not applicable for the arguments (ToIntFunction<MainTest.Hosting>,
    // Hosting::getName)
    Map<Integer, String> resultWithToIntFuncMapper =
        list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(sampleToIntMapper, Hosting::getName));

  }

  private ToIntFunction<Hosting> sampleToIntMapper = (Hosting input) -> {
    return input.getId();
  };

  private Function<Hosting, Integer> sampleMapper = (Hosting input) -> {
    return input.getId();
  };

  @Getter
  @Setter
  @AllArgsConstructor
  class Hosting {
    private int Id;
    private String name;
    private long websites;

  }

}
```

I tried to change the `Function` to `ToIntFunction` based on the [SonarQube rule](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/type/Code%20Smell/RSPEC-4276?search=Functional%20Interfaces%20should%20be%20as%20specialised)

> **'Functional Interfaces should be as specialised as possible - squid:S4276'**

But I'm getting compilation error there when changing that to 'ToIntFunction'. Please assist to resolve this.

Comment: What argument types does `toMap` accept?

Comment: It requires two `Function` to map the key and value. But I'm not able to use `ToIntFunction` instead of 'Function`. Is the sonar rule is irrelevant?

Comment: And is `ToIntFunction` a `Function`?

Comment: No. definitely not. But why sonarqube reports the `function` usage as a codesmell? It says 'Functional Interfaces should be as specialised as possible'

Comment: Would `sampleToIntMapper::apply` work?

Comment: Sonarqube reports it because *someone* added that rule to it. That doesn't mean that it is a useful rule.

Comment: Its False Positive. [Jira Ticket Opened](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-3265)

Answer (score 0):

`toMap` takes `Function<T, R>` as argument.

Maybe you need to declare own functional interface like below

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface ToIntegerFunction<T> extends Function<T, Integer> {
    Integer apply(T arg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Collectors.toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) takes `Function` as an argument, But you are trying to pass [ToIntFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/ToIntFunction.html) which has no relationship with [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html)

```
public static <T,K,U> Collector<T,?,Map<K,U>> toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper,
                                                Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper)
```

So either use `Function` approach

```
Map<Integer, String> resultWithFuncMapper =
    list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(sampleMapper, Hosting::getName));
```

or Method Reference approach

```
 Map<Integer, String> resultWithMethodRef =
    list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Hosting::getId, Hosting::getName));
```

Comment: But when I use `Function`, sonarqube reports it as codesmell. `'Functional Interfaces should be as specialised as possible - squid:S4276'`

Comment: That might be a bug with sonarqube, I'm not sure https://github.com/ursjoss/scipamato/issues/97 @MasterPo But you can go with method reference, why do you need separate `Function` again ?

Comment: I can go with method reference. I'm just trying to find what are the available options are and how it can be used. that's why. :)

Comment: For sure `ToIntFunction` is not going to work @MasterPo and remaining approaches are good

Answer (score 0):

You could use Number instead of Integer to make it accept nullable Integers, for example:

```
private Function<Hosting, Number> sampleMapper = (Hosting input) -> {
    return input.getId();
};
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."